# Should my factory return an object with helper methods or should I use prototype?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner with angular and I try to understand if I should user a factory like that:

```
app.factory('FoobarServices', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var Foobar = {
        // Model
    };

    return {
        getFoobar: function () {

        },
        setFoobar: function (Foobar) {

        },
        update: function (foobar) {

        },
        delete: function (id)

        }
    };
}]);
```

Or something like:

```
app.factory('Fooba', ['$http', function($http) {  
    function Foobar(foobar) {
        // Initialize foobar
    };
    Foobar.prototype = {
        getFoobars: function() {

        },
        setFoobar: function(foobar) {

        },
        update: function(foobar) {

        },
        delete: function(id) {

        },
    };
    return Foobar;
}]);
```

I'm not sure to understand what's the pros and cons of each pattern, and which one is more suitable for an angular project.

Could you please tell me which one should I use?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the `factory` should never return methods. Factory is used to return `Objects`. If you want to return only methods, you should use `service`. :)

Comment: For singleton objects, you should not use a prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use your service.
Factory is usually being used to store some constructor from which you can later instantiate some objects.

For example:

```
app.factory('Client', function () {
  function Client (name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Client.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name + '!');
  }

  return Client;
})

.controller('ClientController', function (Client) {
  var bob = new Client('Bob');
})
```

If your service is singleton, you can register it as `service` instead of `factory` and angular will create an instance for you.
Or you can register it as factory but return some object with methods. It is useful when you don't want to deal with context (`this`) inside your service logic:

```
app.factory('ClientStorage', function () {

    function set () {
      // to be implemented
    }

    function get () {
      // to be implemented
    }

    return {
      get: get,
      set: set
    };
})
```